# how to iterate multiple variables up and back down repeatedly

Tags: python

I have written some code that cycles multiple variables through a range of roughly 1-255 at different rates in order to cycle through some colors in a graphics program I am writing.  My code works, but it is a bit ugly and repeats a lot of code.  How could I write this more elegantly?

```
...

toggleDecrementi = False
toggleDecrementj = False
toggleDecrementk = False

...

for x in range(1,10000):
...

    if i >= 250:
        toggleDecrementi = True
    elif i <= 5:
        toggleDecrementi = False
    if toggleDecrementi == False:
        i = i + 2.5
    else:
        i = i - 2

    if j >= 255:
        toggleDecrementj = True
    elif j <= 0:
        toggleDecrementj = False
    if toggleDecrementj == False:
        j = j + 1
    else:
        j = j - 1

    if k >= 240:
        toggleDecrementk = True
    elif k <= 10:
        toggleDecrementk = False
    if toggleDecrementk == False:
        k = k + 3
    else:
        k = k - 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a single class for your color may simplify your code.

Here's an example:

*Note: It doesn't support different values for increment/decrement.*

```
class ColorCycler:
    def __init__(self, color_int, color_min, color_max, color_change_value):
        self.value = color_int
        self.min = color_min
        self.max = color_max
        self.change = color_change_value
        self.increment = True

    def __next__(self):
        if self.value >= self.max:
            self.increment = False
        elif self.value <= self.min:
            self.increment = True

        if self.increment:
            self.value += self.change
        else:
            self.value -= self.change

        return self.value

r = ColorCycler(130, 5, 250, 2)            
g = ColorCycler(120, 0, 255, 1)
b = ColorCycler(200, 10, 240, 3)

for i in range(10):
    print(next(r), next(g), next(b))
```

Gives you:

```
128 119 197
126 118 194
124 117 191
122 116 188
120 115 185
118 114 182
116 113 179
114 112 176
112 111 173
110 110 170
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also contract the logic further by combining the boundary checks and the invert operation, to something like:

```
    if not self.min < self.value < self.max:
        self.change = self.change * -1
    self.value = max(min(self.value + self.change, self.max), self.min)
```

Naturally you may want to constrain the result value as initial conditions, if outside, will result in the number flip-flop between two values outside it.  That said, contracting the code doesn't necessarily make it simpler to understand, but in this case it's relatively straightforward.